# How to make the page not reload clicking a button

Tags: php, jquery, html

I just learn html and css and I need to do a project that build a robot and control the robot using website.

When I click the button it will go to other page or reload

How do I pass the value in the button without reloading the page?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>RPOC</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="welcome.php" method="post" type='submit'>
            <button>FORWARD
            <input type="hidden" name="value" value="1"><br></button>
        </form>

        <form action="welcome.php" method="post" type='submit'>
            <button>BACKWARD
            <input type="hidden" name="value" value="2"><br></button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you not found/tried anything before posting?

Comment: `<form action="welcome.php" method="post" type='submit'>` that's invalid.

Comment: Put the value on the submit button: `<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="value" value="1">FORWARD</button>
    <button type="submit" name="value" value="2">BACKWARD</button></form>` assuming welcome.php acts on `$_POST["value"]`

Comment: I'd suggest looking up ajax and how it works.

Comment: pass the value where? To the server? If so then ajax is what you need. Lots of examples online already.

Answer (score 0):

Your html contains a few mistakes. Try this:

```
<body>
    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="value" value="1">
        <button type="submit">FORWARD</button>
    </form>

    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="value" value="2">
        <button type="submit">FORWARD</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

1. Removed type="submit" from form element
2. Removed hidden input in button element
3. Added type="submit" to button element

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a ajax call...

Try something like this, but you will have to make a ajax.page.php file.
You can learn more at: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```js
$('#btoForward01').click(function(e){
    var value01 = $('#value01').val();
    var fullURL = "ajax.page.php?value01=" + value01;
    //console.log(urlCompleta);
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: fullURL, 
        success: function(result){
            console.log('evething alright');
        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function(){alert( "Page not found" );},
            500: function(){alert( "PHP Error" );}
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<body>
    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="value" value="1" id="value01">
        <button type="submit" id="btoForward01">FORWARD</button>
    </form>
</body>
```